# merge two rows of n dimension by considering one column

Tags: r, merge, rows

### I have a matrix, that has been formed after using `cbind()`

```
   ! ? c e i k l t
dif     0 0 1 0 0 0 
dor     1 0 0 0 0 0
dor     0 0 0 0 0 1
same    0 0 0 1 0 0 
same    0 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

Suggest me a code in R that could merge the rows as below

---

```
   ! ? c e i k l t
same    1 1 0 1 0 0 
dif     0 0 1 0 0 0 
dor     1 0 0 0 0 1
```

---

Thank you..

Comment: Are `! ? c e i k l t` your column names?

Comment: Ya. So the data above is sample. I have thousands of rows and columns.  All these were in excel, so imported data using column names(header=TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="ID c e i k l t
dif     0 0 1 0 0 0 
dor     1 0 0 0 0 0
dor     0 0 0 0 0 1
same    0 0 0 1 0 0 
same    0 1 0 0 0 0")

require(plyr)

ddply(df,.(ID),function(x)colSums(x[,-1]))

    ID c e i k l t
1  dif 0 0 1 0 0 0
2  dor 1 0 0 0 0 1
3 same 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Command acknowledged:

```
aggregate(df[, -1], list(df[, 1]), function(x) {
  Reduce("|", x)
})
#   Group.1 c e i k l t
# 1     dif 0 0 1 0 0 0
# 2     dor 1 0 0 0 0 1
# 3    same 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the sum, or do you want the logical OR:

Logical OR:

```
require(functional)
aggregate(. ~ ID, data=df, FUN=Compose(any, as.numeric))
    ID c e i k l t
1  dif 0 0 1 0 0 0
2  dor 1 0 0 0 0 1
3 same 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Sum:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

The result here is the same.